# Windows 8 language settings don't change the language everywhere

Tags: windows-8, language

I just bought a new computer with windows 8 on it from Germany, so when it shipped over everything was in German. I was able to get around that and download the English language pack but I noticed that some of the tags were still in German. Among these are some of the default group names for the apps and some things on the login screen like in the password bar it says "Kennwort". Is it possible to permanently chance the operating language to English?

(I even tried deleting the German language profile but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Open a command prompt as administrator, and run this command: `dism /online /get-intl & bcdedit /enum all` Then post here the full output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows 8 hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and type in the search `Region`, click on the Region and go to the Administrative Tab and click on the copy settings and make the languages changes system wide.

[image]

Comment: You would also want to change that bottom section to English (language for non-unicode programs).

Comment: Alright thx a lot man :D