# How to change the language on a windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I need to reset the langauge on a lenovo windows 8 but everytime I change the language pack, things like the tiles and the right side menu bar stay in english. How can i fix this? How can I convert everything to a different language

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 8 language settings don't change the language everywhere](http://superuser.com/questions/805754/windows-8-language-settings-dont-change-the-language-everywhere)

Comment: @DavidPostill I already tried the method used in the explanation and it did not change anything

Comment: If people perceive this as the same question as the proposed duplicate (and it seems to be), it will get the same response.  If the answer on the other question didn't work, you need to better differentiate your question from the other and also explain what didn't work on that answer.  That's the only way you will attract different answers.

Comment: If you've tried methods from existing answers then you need to tell us what the things you've tried are, what happened when you tried them, and any error messages or other useful information.  As it stands this question *is* a duplicate because it adds nothing new, as fixer mentioned you need to help us to help you.